# Changing a bitmap Resource

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using a class to add a bar which is a bitmap:

```
public HpBar(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        
        
        Bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.hp5);
        Width = Metrics.WidthPixels / 12;
        Height = Width * Bitmap.Height / Bitmap.Width;
        Bitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(Bitmap, Width, Height, true);

        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        
    }
```

In an Update() method of another activity I'm trying to change the bitmap's Resource to a different image. The problem is that I need to enter a context which I can't get because I'm in the Update() method which does not receives parameters .

```
public void Update()
    {
        
        List<Bird> birdsToBeRemoved = new List<Bird>();
        List<Stone> stonesToBeRemoved = new List<Stone>();
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        background.MoveObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < birds.Count; i++)
        {
            
            Bird bird = birds.ElementAt(i);
            bird.MoveObject();
            if(Rect.Intersects(bird.GetColisionShape(),hero.GetColisionShape()) && HpCount > 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Plane Got hit");
                HpCount--;
                hpBar.Bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources, Resource.Drawable.hp4);
                birdsToBeRemoved.Add(bird);
            }
```

I've tried using System.Resources but when the bitmap is supposed to change the app gets stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to your desription,I don't know the specific usage scenario.

But in generally, if you want to use the `Context` in a class, you can pass it as a parameter in the constructor of this class.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class HpBar
{
    Context  mContext;
    Bitmap mBitmap;

    public HpBar(Context context) {

        mContext =  context;

        Bitmap mBitmap  = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(mContext.Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon);
        //Width = Metrics.WidthPixels / 12;
        //Height = Width * Bitmap.Height / Bitmap.Width;
        //Bitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(Bitmap, Width, Height, true);

        //X = 0;
        //Y = 0;

    }
}
```

Call method `Update` in your activity:

```
      void Update() { 
        HpBar hpBar = new HpBar(this);
    
    }
```

Comment: The thing is when I try to create the hpBar it Doesn't recognize "this" as a context and it should be converted

Comment: Could you please post more code snippets (e.g. the code of the `HpBar`)?

Comment: What I posted is basically the code of HpBar class. The Update method is located in another class. I updated the question and added some more of the code from Update

Comment: If the `update` is a method in an activity, it should recognize the first parameter (`this.Resources`) of   method `BitmapFactory.DecodeResource`.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can help you better?

Comment: It just makes the app freeze

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by words `It just makes the app freeze` .